# How to display both key and value after applying filter and map on Map Interface?

Tags: java, java-8

```
//i have a list of student type 
List<Student> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        list2.add(new Student(101, "piyush"));
        list2.add(new Student(102, "Raman"));
        list2.add(new Student(109, "Raman"));

//i converted this list to Map




    Map<Integer, String> map3=list2.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.
                    toMap(Student::getStudentId, Student::getStudName ));

//now i converted it to stream and applied some fiter and map

       map3.entrySet()
    .stream().filter(i -> i.getKey()==131 || i.getKey()==101).map(i-> i.getValue().toUpperCase())
    .forEach(System.out::println);


//above code displays only name in UpperCase
```

// but i want to display both id and name(Upper case) what should i do.

```
     map3.entrySet()
    .stream().filter(i -> i.getKey()==131 || i.getKey()==101)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

/*this code displays both id and name so y the above forEach loop  is not displaying it.
i even tried to store result in Map using collector but that is not working.*/

// not working

```
    Map<Integer,String> map4= map3.entrySet()
    .stream().filter(i -> i.getKey()==131 || i.getKey()==101).map(i-> i.getValue().toUpperCase()).
    collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Answer (score 3):

If the output is not what you desire, this means the `Map.Entry` implementation returned by your stream probably doesn't override `Object`'s `toString`, so you have to specify how to print the entry:

```
map3.entrySet()
    .stream().filter(e -> e.getKey() == 131 || e.getKey() == 101)
    .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " " + e.getValue().toUpperCase()));
```

However, looking at your full code, I'm not sure you need to create that map in the first place. You can filter the original list and get the same output:

```
list2.stream()
     .filter(s -> s.getStudentId() == 131 || s.getStudentId() == 101)
     .forEach(s -> System.out.println(s.getStudentId() + " " + s.getStudName ().toUpperCase()));
```

BTW, if your original list would contain multiple `Student`s having the same ID, your `Collectors.toMap` would fail.

Comment: In his first example he uses `map` and gets only the values.

Comment: @MuratK.Yep, since you lose the key if you map each entry to its corresponding value.

Comment: Thanks @Eran...solved and understood. but what can we do if our list contains duplicate id. and we are still coverting it to Map

Comment: @Piyusharora That depends on what do you want the output to be in that case.

Answer (score 0):

> this code displays both id and name so y the above forEach loop is not displaying it

- Following code snippet not displaying key cause intermediate operation `.map(i-> i.getValue().toUpperCase())`process elements from stream and return stream of student value element (`i-> i.getValue()`)  not key.

  ```
  map3.entrySet()
  stream().filter(i -> i.getKey()==131 || i.getKey()==101).map(i->i.getValue().toUpperCase())
  .forEach(System.out::println);
  ```
- Following code showing key and value because you just `filter()` stream element  and it returns  streams of student element i.e student(131), student(101) which you iterate over through.

  ```
  map3.entrySet()
  .stream().filter(i -> i.getKey()==131 || i.getKey()==101)
  .forEach(System.out::println);
  ```